# android forensic

Tags: android

I would like to retrieve the browser history from the com.android.browser and save it into a file in sdcard. I am able to do soo for the contacts but not the browser history.Don't know what went wrong. They only prompt the error ***bind or column index out of range: handle 0x27a6d0***.

What would be the best format for the file to be xml, txt or??

**These are my codes**

```
package fypj.ReadContacts;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.Browser;
import android.provider.Browser.BookmarkColumns;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal;

public class ReadContacts extends Activity {

   // To suppress notational clutter and make structure clearer, define some shorthand constants.

   private static final Uri URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
   private static final Uri PURI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
   private static final Uri EURI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
   private static final Uri AURI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI;
   private static final String ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
   private static final String DNAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
   private static final String HPN = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
   private static final String LOOKY = ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY;
   private static final String CID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;

   private static final String EID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID;
   private static final String AID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTACT_ID;
   private static final String PNUM = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;
   private static final String PHONETYPE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE;
   private static final String EMAIL = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;
   private static final String EMAILTYPE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE;
   private static final String STREET = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET;
   private static final String CITY = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY;
   private static final String STATE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION;
   private static final String POSTCODE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE;
   private static final String COUNTRY = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY;

   private static final Uri URI1 = android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI;
   private static final String bHistoryTITLE = Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE;
   private static final String bHistoryURL = Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL;
   private static final String bHistoryBOOKMARK = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK;
   private static final String bHistoryVISITS = Browser.BookmarkColumns.VISITS;
   private static final String ID1 = Browser.BookmarkColumns._ID    ;
   //private static final String BID = Browser.BookmarkColumns.
   //private static final String DNAME = Browser.BookmarkColumns.DISPLAY_NAME;
   //private static final String HPN = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
   //private static final String LOOKY = Browser.BookmarkColumns.LOOKUP_KEY;

   private String id;
   private String lookupKey;
   private String name;
   private String street;
   private String city;
   private String state;
   private String postcode;
   private String country;
   private String ph[];
   private String phType[];
   private String em[];
   private String emType[];

   private String id1;
   private String URL;
   private String BTitle;
   private String BURL;
   private String BBOOKMARK;
   private String BVISITS;
   private String browserTITLE[];
   private String browserURL[];
   private String browserBOOKMARK[];
   private String browserVISITS[];

   private File root;
   private int emcounter;
   private int phcounter;
   private int addcounter;



   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);




      // Check that external media available and writable
      checkExternalMedia();
      Contacts();
      browser();

   }


   /**  Method to check whether external media available and writable and to find the
      root of the external file system. */   

   private void checkExternalMedia () {
      // Check external media availability.  This is adapted from
      // http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal
      boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
      boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
      String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

      if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
         // We can read and write the media
         mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
      } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
         // We can only read the media
         mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
         mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
      } else {
         // Can't read or write
         mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
      }

      // Find the root of the external storage and output external storage info to screen   
      root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 

   }
   public void Contacts(){
    // Allow for up to 5 email and phone entries for a contact
          em = new String[5];
          emType = new String[5];
          ph = new String[5];
          phType = new String[5];

          /** Open a PrintWriter wrapping a FileOutputStream so that we can send output from a
          query of the Contacts database to a file on the SD card.  Must wrap the whole thing 
          in a try-catch to catch file not found and i/o exceptions. Note that since we are writing
          to external media we must add a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the 
          manifest file.  Otherwise  a FileNotFoundException will be thrown. */

          // This will set up output to /sdcard/download/phoneData.txt if /sdcard is the root of
          // the external storage.  See the project WriteSDCard for more information about
          // writing to a file on the SD card.

          File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/download");
          dir.mkdirs();
          //File file = new File(dir, "phoneData.rtf");
          File file = new File(dir, "phoneData.accdb");


          try{
             FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
             PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);

             // Main loop to query the contacts database, extracting the information.  See
             // http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/

             ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
             Cursor cu = cr.query(URI, null, null, null, null);
             if (cu.getCount() > 0) {   

                // Loop over all contacts
                while (cu.moveToNext()) {   

                   // Initialize storage variables for the new contact
                   street = "";
                   city = "";
                   state = "";
                   postcode = "";
                   country = "";

                   // Get ID information (id, name and lookup key) for this contact. id is an identifier
                   // number, name is the name associated with this row in the database, and
                   // lookupKey is an opaque value that contains hints on how to find the contact 
                   // if its row id changed as a result of a sync or aggregation.

                   id = cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex(ID));
                   name = cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex(DNAME));          
                   lookupKey = cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex(LOOKY));              
                   // Append list of contacts to the scrollable TextView on the screen.



                   // Query phone numbers for this contact (may be more than one), so use a 
                   // while-loop to move the cursor to the next row until moveToNext() returns
                   // false, indicating no more rows. Store the results in arrays since there may
                   // be more than one phone number stored per contact. The if-statement
                   // enclosing everything ensures that the contact has at least one phone 
                   // number stored in the Contacts database.

                   phcounter = 0;
                   if (Integer.parseInt(cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex(HPN))) > 0) {                
                      Cursor pCur = cr.query(PURI,  null, CID + " = ?",  new String[]{id}, null);
                      while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                         ph[phcounter] = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(PNUM));
                         phType[phcounter]  = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(PHONETYPE)); 
                         phcounter ++;
                      } 
                      pCur.close();
                   }

                   // Query email addresses for this contact (may be more than one), so use a 
                   // while-loop to move the cursor to the next row until moveToNext() returns
                   // false, indicating no more rows. Store the results in arrays since there may
                   // be more than one email address stored per contact.

                   emcounter = 0;
                   Cursor emailCur = cr.query(EURI, null, EID + " = ?",  new String[]{id}, null); 
                   while (emailCur.moveToNext()) { 
                      em[emcounter] =  emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(EMAIL));
                      emType[emcounter] =  emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(EMAILTYPE));
                      emcounter ++;
                   } 
                   emailCur.close();

                   // Query Address (assume only one address stored for simplicity). If there is
                   // more than one address we loop through all with the while-loop but keep
                   // only the last one.

                   addcounter = 0;
                   Cursor addCur = cr.query(AURI, null, AID + " = ?",  new String[]{id}, null); 
                   while (addCur.moveToNext()) { 
                      street = addCur.getString(addCur.getColumnIndex(STREET));
                      city = addCur.getString(addCur.getColumnIndex(CITY));
                      state = addCur.getString(addCur.getColumnIndex(STATE));
                      postcode = addCur.getString(addCur.getColumnIndex(POSTCODE));
                      country = addCur.getString(addCur.getColumnIndex(COUNTRY));
                      addcounter ++;
                   } 
                   addCur.close();

                   // Write identifiers for this contact to the SD card file
                        //pw.println(name+" ID="+id+" LOOKUP_KEY="+lookupKey);
                   pw.println(name);
                   // Write list of phone numbers for this contact to SD card file
                   for(int i=0; i<phcounter; i++){
                      //pw.println("   phone="+ ph[i]+" type="+phType[i] + " ("
                         //+ getPhoneType(phType[i]) + ") ");
                       pw.println("   phone="+ ph[i]+" ("
                               + getPhoneType(phType[i]) + ") ");
                   }
                   // Write list of email addresses for this contact to SD card file
                   for(int i=0; i<emcounter; i++){
                      pw.println("   email="+ em[i]+" type="+emType[i] + " ("
                         + getEmailType(emType[i]) + ") ");
                   }
                   // If street address is stored for contact, write it to SD card file
                   if(addcounter > 0){
                      if(street != null) pw.println("   street="+street);
                      if(city != null) pw.println("   city="+city);
                      if(state != null) pw.println("   state/region="+state);
                      if(postcode != null) pw.println("   postcode="+postcode);
                      if(country != null) pw.println("   country="+country);
                   }
                }
             }       
             // Flush the PrintWriter to ensure everything pending is output before closing
             pw.flush();
             pw.close();
             f.close();       
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             Log.i("MEDIA", "*************** File not found. Did you" +
                " add a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the manifest file? ");
          } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
          } 
   }

   /** Method to return label corresponding to phone type code. Data for correspondence from
      http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html */

   private String getPhoneType(String index){
      if(index.trim().equals( "1")){
         return "home";
      } else if (index.trim().equals("2")){
         return "mobile";
      } else if (index.trim().equals("3")){
         return "work";
      } else if (index.trim().equals("7")){
         return "other";
      } else {
         return "?";
      }
   }  

   /** Method to return label corresponding to email type code. Data for correspondence from
      http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.
      CommonDataKinds.Email.html  */

   private String getEmailType(String index){
      if(index.trim().equals( "1")){
         return "home";
      } else if (index.trim().equals("2")){
         return "work";
      } else if (index.trim().equals("3")){
         return "other";
      } else if (index.trim().equals("4")){
         return "mobile";
      } else {
         return "?";
      }
   }

   public void browser(){
       //create file
       File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DATASTOREAGE");
          dir.mkdirs();
          File file = new File(dir, "browserHistory.rtf");

          try{
             FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
             PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);

             // Main loop to query the contacts database, extracting the information.  See
             // http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/

             ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
             Cursor cu = cr.query(URI1, null, null, null, null);
             if (cu.getCount() > 0) {   

                // Loop over all contacts
                while (cu.moveToNext()) {   

                   // Initialize storage variables for the new contact
                   BTitle = "";
                   BURL = "";
                   BBOOKMARK = "";
                   BVISITS = "";

                   // Get ID information (id, name and lookup key) for this contact. id is an identifier
                   // number, name is the name associated with this row in the database, and
                   // lookupKey is an opaque value that contains hints on how to find the contact 
                   // if its row id changed as a result of a sync or aggregation.

                   id1 = cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex(ID1));
                   URL = cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex(BookmarkColumns.TITLE));          
                   //lookupKey = cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex(LOOKY));            
                   // Append list of contacts to the scrollable TextView on the screen.



                   // Query phone numbers for this contact (may be more than one), so use a 
                   // while-loop to move the cursor to the next row until moveToNext() returns
                   // false, indicating no more rows. Store the results in arrays since there may
                   // be more than one phone number stored per contact. The if-statement
                   // enclosing everything ensures that the contact has at least one phone 
                   // number stored in the Contacts database.

                   phcounter = 0;

                      Cursor bCur = cr.query(URI1,  null, ID1,  new String[]{id1}, null);
                      while (bCur.moveToNext()) {
                         browserTITLE[phcounter] = bCur.getString(bCur.getColumnIndex(bHistoryTITLE));
                         browserURL[phcounter]  = bCur.getString(bCur.getColumnIndex(bHistoryURL));
                         browserBOOKMARK[phcounter]  = bCur.getString(bCur.getColumnIndex(bHistoryBOOKMARK));
                         browserVISITS[phcounter]  = bCur.getString(bCur.getColumnIndex(bHistoryVISITS));
                         phcounter ++;
                      } 
                      bCur.close();
                   }





                   // Write identifiers for this contact to the SD card file
                        //pw.println(name+" ID="+id+" LOOKUP_KEY="+lookupKey);
                   pw.println(BTitle+" ID="+id1+" LOOKUP_KEY="+lookupKey);
                   pw.println(BURL);
                   pw.println(BBOOKMARK);
                   pw.println(BVISITS);
                }

             // Flush the PrintWriter to ensure everything pending is output before closing
             pw.flush();
             pw.close();
             f.close();       
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             Log.i("MEDIA", "*************** File not found. Did you" +
                " add a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the manifest file? ");
          } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
          } 
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selection column is wrong in the second query of URI1 the line should read:

```
Cursor bCur = cr.query(URI1,  null, ID1+"=?",  new String[]{id1}, null);
```

The second query isn't needed though. You are first quering all columns, extracting the ID from all columns. And then doing a nest query on the all columns for a particular id.
You don't need the nest query, the first query will have all the data you need.

The question of the best file format. That would depend on what is going to consume the data you are creating.

Comment: what do you mean by what is going to consume the data??

Comment: When you generate the file with the bookmarks, contracts etc. What are you going to do with it? If it is going to be read by a person then txt, csv makes sense. If a computer is going to read the file then xml or json make more sense.

Comment: oh, the file is to be read by the user. The problem is if i use .txt the data are show are in a mess.Is there anyway to organise it or something like that??

Comment: Not automatically, perhaps use something like a CSV file, then at least the can open it in a spreadsheet app.

Comment: oh, i have change to cvc format instead. I realise that i am only able to retrieve the first url.